# Table of constants in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, visual-c++-6

I'm working on a project with a software that uses C++ compiler (VisualStudio 2010 C++). The software is for making numerical model for real electric circuits. I write some codes in different sections in the software, ir's a C++ code but some variables must have some prefixes (SeqInteger instead of Integer, ptVar if Var is the name of a connection in the model, etc ...). The software generates then cpp files with the code I wrote and other sections in it.

The issue : I am trying to initiate a table contaning constant values, to do so, I wrote :

```
SeqReal A[4];

A[4]={1 , 2, 1 , 3};
```

However, I am getting this error :

```
compiling src/SeqClass__cpl.cpp
SeqClass__cpl.cpp
src/SeqClass__cpl.cpp(74) : error C2059: syntax error : '{'
src/SeqClass__cpl.cpp(74) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
src/SeqClass__cpl.cpp(74) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
make: *** [WinNT\debug64/SeqClass__cpl.obj] Error 512
```

I understand that the syntax of my line is wrong, but how should I write it ? It used to work for me like this before.

I hope I made myself clear. I only gave this simple example, but in fact, I am having the same error while trying to initiate matrices of 28*16 shape.

Thank you !

Comment: Do you *need* to declare and assign separately? Otherwise you can initialize in a single line.

Comment: You can't assign the array values that way, only initialize. You could use a std::vector instead.

Comment: Why did you tag visual-c++-6 if you're using VS 2010? Please clarify.

Comment: @cigien yes, what I do now is that I declare in a section, and then redeclare and assign in the same line in another section

Comment: But that means you are declaring 2 different arrays. You can only *initialize* something when it's first created. See my answer below for an alternative solution.

Comment: @cigien actually no, because in the section where I declare without assigning, all the variables of my object are declared. All the other sections have their variables declared in this section, but when it comes to arrays, I have to declare it so that I can fin it in the other sections, and then initliaze it in the initializing section.

Comment: @Momo cigien is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to declare an array, and *later* assign to it using an initializer list, you could do:

```
int i = 0;
for (int v : {1 , 2, 1 , 3})
  A[i++] = v;
```

Comment: That's great. Note that you can't accept multiple answers, so only accept the one that solves your problem. You can upvote multiple answers if they help.

Answer (score 0):

You are (probably) trying to declare, and then assign to a C-style array using a [brace-enclosed list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization#Initialization_from_brace-enclosed_lists), which is not allowed. Initialize instead:

```
SeqReal A[4] = {1, 2, 1, 3};
```

Or use a container such as the [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array<SeqReal, 4> arr;
arr = {1, 2, 1, 3};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Actually I am declaring in a section and then initializing in another section, that's why I have to write it in two lines.

Comment: @Momo That is not possible. Initialisation happens at the point of definition; no way around that. (That's why it's called "initialisation"!) You'll need a workaround that supports later assignment to either individual elements or to the whole container. Your C++ book will explain this.

Comment: actually OP assigns not to the array but to one element, depending on what `SeqReal` is that could be fine. But yeah I suppose this answer will help

Comment: @idclev463035818 It's clear they were trying to assign to an array they thought was called `A[4]`, not to an individual element. Even if they were, it would not be "fine", because `A[4]` is out of bounds.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Well spotted, that was my impression at first. But erroneous reading out of bounds with `A[4]` suggests the OP wants to assign to an entire array.